# Unable to start MySQL Server - 'mysql.sock' missing

Tags: mysql, macos

I am unable to start MySQL Server on Mac OSx Mountain Lion. This may be because there's no file named as 'mysql.sock' anymore. On running mysql command on terminal i get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

MySql server was running fine on my machine for a long time before this issue. What could be causing this error ?

Update :

i have tried running mysqld_safe but no use and then running '/usr/local/mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64/scripts/mysql_install_db' but this is what i get

> FATAL ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults
>
> If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
>   copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.
>
> If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
>   level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
>   pointing to that location.

Comment: what socket address is given in mysql configuration file

Comment: Yes i am aware of that, i tried starting it manually through the terminal and also through Preferences->MySQL but both didnt work

Comment: Check the socket address in your MySQL configuration file

Comment: @Rudra mysql.default_socket -> /tmp/mysql.sock